# Error installing Visual Studio 2017 with Xamarin iOS on Mac

Tags: macos, xamarin, xamarin.ios, visual-studio-2017

When installing Visual Studio 2017 the installation fails at the Xamarin.iOS installation:

```
[2020-03-22 18:01:15.337] [Info] Installing software item 'Xamarin.iOS'
[2020-03-22 18:01:15.338] [Debug] Starting Xcode detection
[2020-03-22 18:01:15.338] [Info] Xamarin.iOS is waiting for download to finish.
[2020-03-22 18:01:15.540] [Debug] Detected the following Xcode versions
[2020-03-22 18:01:15.541] [Debug] /Applications/Xcode.app (version 11.3.1)
[2020-03-22 18:01:15.546] [Debug] Xcode is installed or not required - no need to remind.
[2020-03-22 18:03:02.640] [Debug] Running '/usr/sbin/installer -pkg <USER_HOME>/Library/Caches/XamarinInstaller/Universal/downloads/xamarin.ios-12.2.1.16.pkg -target / -verboseR' with privileges
[2020-03-22 18:03:02.640] [Debug] Preauthenticating the command
[2020-03-22 18:03:12.297] [Warning] Installer passed unexpected string: installer: Package name is Xamarin.iOS
[2020-03-22 18:03:12.297] [Warning] Installer passed unexpected string: installer: Installing at base path /
[2020-03-22 18:03:14.215] [Warning] Installer passed unexpected string: installer: The install failed. (Die Installation ist aufgrund eines Fehlers fehlgeschlagen. Wende dich an den Hersteller der Software. Das Paket versucht Inhalte auf dem Systemvolume zu installieren.)
[2020-03-22 18:03:14.215] [Info] Waiting for the child process to finish running with root privileges.
[2020-03-22 18:03:14.221] [Error] Command '/usr/sbin/installer' failed with error code '1'
[2020-03-22 18:03:14.221] [Debug] Installer finished without success. Exit code was 1
[2020-03-22 18:03:14.221] [Info] Retrying installation (attempt #2, 1 to go)
[2020-03-22 18:03:14.221] [Debug] Running '/usr/sbin/installer -pkg <USER_HOME>/Library/Caches/XamarinInstaller/Universal/downloads/xamarin.ios-12.2.1.16.pkg -target / -verboseR' with privileges
[2020-03-22 18:03:14.623] [Warning] Installer passed unexpected string: installer: Package name is Xamarin.iOS
[2020-03-22 18:03:14.623] [Warning] Installer passed unexpected string: installer: Installing at base path /
[2020-03-22 18:03:16.344] [Warning] Installer passed unexpected string: installer: The install failed. (Die Installation ist aufgrund eines Fehlers fehlgeschlagen. Wende dich an den Hersteller der Software. Das Paket versucht Inhalte auf dem Systemvolume zu installieren.)
[2020-03-22 18:03:16.344] [Info] Waiting for the child process to finish running with root privileges.
[2020-03-22 18:03:16.344] [Error] Command '/usr/sbin/installer' failed with error code '1'
[2020-03-22 18:03:16.348] [Debug] Installer finished without success. Exit code was 1
```

I'm running Xcode 11.3.1 and macOS 10.15.3 (19D76). Clearing the XamarinInstaller cache did nothing. I'm thankfull for any hints.

Comment: You need to use Visual Studio *2019* for Mac as Catalina+ does not allow system partition ('/') installs.

Comment: I'm able to install VS2017 without additional components why is the Xamarin.iOS any different?

Comment: Is there a particular reason VS2019 wont do?

Comment: Company policy requires me to use VS2017